# In Angular, how to handle promise reject when using async/await

Tags: javascript, angularjs, async-await, ecmascript-2017

In Angular, if I use promise, the code would be

```
let promise = this.$resource('www.example.com.au/request.json').get().$promise
promise.then(data => {
    //promise solved
}, () => {
   //promise rejected
})
```

when it comes to async/await
the code becomes

```
async getData() {
    let data = await this.$resource('www.example.com.au/request.json').get().$promise
    this.localData = {...data}
}
```

but this is only for promise solved. if it is promise rejected, what should I do? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the promise is rejected, an error will be thrown. Use `try...catch`:

```
async getData() {
  try {
    let data = await this.$resource('www.example.com.au/request.json').get().$promise
    this.localData = {...data};
  } catch(error) {
    // promise rejected
  }
}
```